# How to break and convert header into multiheader in pandas? This is a focused question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, multi-index

| Names | ABCBaseCIP00 | ABCBaseCIP01 | ABCBaseCIP02 | ABC1CIP00 | ABC1CIP01 | ABC1CIP02 | ABC2CIP00 | ABC2CIP01 | ABC2CIP02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Y | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Z | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

I have above dataframe, I am looking to break column headers by name(`ABCBase|ABC1|ABC2)` and code(`CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02`) to get below table as output.

Can anyone suggest how can that be done in pandas? This is dynamic data so do not want to hardcode anything.I was trying multiindex and slicing but not getting exact result.

```
|     |ABCBase          |ABC1             |ABC2             |
|-----|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|Names|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  X  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |
|  Y  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |
|  Z  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ABCBaseCIP00': [1, 1, 1],
                   'ABCBaseCIP01': [2, 2, 2],
                   'ABCBaseCIP02': [3, 3, 3],
                   'ABC1CIP00': [4, 4, 4],
                   'ABC1CIP01': [5, 5, 5],
                   'ABC1CIP02': [6, 6, 6],
                   'ABC2CIP00': [7, 7, 7],
                   'ABC2CIP01': [8, 8, 8],
                   'ABC2CIP02': [9, 9, 9] },
                  index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'] )
lt = []
for col in df.columns:
    cut = col.find('CIP')
    lt.append((col[:cut], col[cut:]))
new_header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lt, names=('name', 'code'))
df.columns = new_header
```

The result of `print(df)`:

```
name ABCBase              ABC1              ABC2            
code   CIP00 CIP01 CIP02 CIP00 CIP01 CIP02 CIP00 CIP01 CIP02
X          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
Y          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
Z          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```